How can I use a separate column value to choose how to fill in values using values_fn in pivot_wider?
I have a dataframe
  descriptions names cutoffs vals
1            a     A      90    1
2            a     A      91    2
3            a     B      90    3
4            a     C      90    4

that I want to pivot_wider(names_from = names, values_from = vals) into the form
  description A B C
1           a 1 3 4

If there are 2+ rows with the same name, I want to fill in values_from with the row with the higher cutoff column value.
I know that if I wanted the max value out of the vals column, I could do values_fn = max, so
I tried adding values_fn = max(cutoffs) as an additional parameter to pivot_wider() but it did not work.
How can I get to my desired end result?

Filter your data first to the rows you want pivoted, then pivot---don't try to do both at once. your_data |> slice_max(cutoffs, n = 1, with_ties = FALSE, by = c(descriptions, names)) |> pivot_wider(names_from = names, values_from = vals)
